# Switching overflow auto to hidden, there is still a scroll bar space

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I have a problem when switching from `overflow:hidden;` to `overflow:auto;`, then back to hidden the text is not occupying the scroll bar space. please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/ay4WV/)

This is my HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor .. lots of text here.</p>
</div>
<button id="switch">Switch div overflow</button>
```

CSS

```
div { height:300px; width:200px; overflow:hidden; background:#CCC;}
```

jQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if($('div').css('overflow') == 'hidden'){
        $('div').css({'overflow':'auto'});
    }else if($('div').css('overflow') == 'auto'){
        $('div').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems that your `<p>` was the issue**

add this:

`p{display:inline}`

made the jquery a little easier too

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').toggleClass('on');
});
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/qYT8c/

Comment: Toggling the class is a better way to do it, just showing him if updating the content, you can gte it redrawn correctly. I like Filevr10 response though.

Comment: It's good to know how to redraw, but better to know why it's happening and how to avoid the issue.

Comment: That was a lack of knowing the css property was causing that. My apologies. :)

Comment: thanks FiLeVeR10. I tried to remove the <p> before and see it working well but don't know how to fix it with the <p> on. :D

Comment: by using the answer above... `p{display:inline}`. You don't need to remove it, just change its display property.

Comment: `display:block` gets stuck sometimes, changing it to `inline` prevents that in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, reset the width again after removing auto overflow, and it will render the text correctly.

```
$('button').click(function(){
if($('div').css('overflow') == 'hidden'){
    $('div').css({'overflow':'auto'});
}else if($('div').css('overflow') == 'auto'){
    $('div').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
            var texts = $('div').text();
            $('div').text('');
            $('div').text(texts);
}
```

});

Comment: The DOM shifts the text, but you need to have it redraw it again. If not, the redrawn text is shifted after redrawing it for the scroll bar. You can make a more elegant way, but that is a basic example of it.

Comment: But it's html inside the div.

Answer (score -1):

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ay4WV/4/)

You don't need to rewrite content or care that it's a `<p>` inside the div.

All you need to do is force the broswer to redraw the element. Simple way is to do these three things in order

1. hide it
2. call `.height()` (`offsetHeight` in vanilla js)
3. show it

jQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if($('div').css('overflow') == 'hidden'){
        $('div').css({'overflow':'auto'})

    }else if($('div').css('overflow') == 'auto'){
        $('div').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
        $('div').hide();
        $('div').height(); // no need to store this anywhere
        $('div').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This redraws the content, and resets the `p`... you're actually doing both of the things you say that you don't need to do, and with a lot more effort than changing the one css property that's causing the issue...